# Mac won't boot into recovery partition

Tags: macos

I've restarted my MacBook and held down cmd+R as I was told by the internet, but it just restarts into the user login screen as if I hadn't done anything. I've also tried option+cmd+R but the same result happened. The same happens with trying to get into single-user mode. Is something wrong?
I'm not very well versed in tech so try and explain in a way a newbie could understand.
It's a 13-inch Macbook Pro with the M1 chip and I bought it this year. It has 512 gigabytes of storage and 16 gigabytes of ram. Its version is Monterey.

Comment: What model year is the MacBook and which version(s) of macOS (OS X) do you have installed? Can you post the output from `diskutil list`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson (I suspect that the reason the OP is trying Recovery and Single User modes may be due to them being unable to log in successfully, so `diskutil` may not be readily accessible.)

Comment: Do you have access to a second Mac? Or at least a second computer?

Comment: I don't have access to a second computer or mac that has the same account.

Comment: What do you mean `that has the same account`? Do you have a second computer available to you?

Comment: M1 Macs don't get to recovery with Cmd/R like Intel Macs [nor do they have a single-user mode in the same way]  - See https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/mac for details

Comment: I don't have a second computer.

Comment: 2nd computer is irrelevant right now. Pushing the correct buttons would be a good first step. Cmd/R doesn't work on M1 Macs.

Comment: Nevermind, it turns out you just hold the power button at boot in a M1.